# Handling interrupted downloads with Paramiko

Tags: ssh, paramiko, scp

I am downloading large files from server 2 using paramiko, and I'm wondering what if download is interrupted in between and I get an incomplete file. In this case would I have to download the entire file again from the start, or is there a better way to handle such cases, i.e. I may start downloading the file from the same offset, where the download was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

SCP protocol does not allow resuming file transfers.

But you can use SFTP instead. It does allow that.